# Does No Guard allow attacks to hit immune Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-series

So after stepping into a discussion about transferring a Machamp with the move one hit KO move Fissure from the recently released virtual console versions of the first generation of games to a new generation to compensate for it's 30% accuracy with No Guard.

My question is whether No Guard will allow a move to affect a target that is otherwise immune due to typing as in the above discussion by using Fissure against a flying type.

Comment: I wonder if this is actually possible, because No Guard is Machamp's second ability. Its first one is Guts, and it may get only that when transfered to Pokebank.

Comment: Ability capsules mate, can switch over between the two

Comment: You're damn right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No Guard does not ignore type immunities (such as a Ground type move against a Flying type or a Fighting type move against a Ghost type), as can be tested in game with a current No-Guard Machamp using a Fighting move against a Ghost type.

However, it does ignore invulnerability in that No-Guard allows a Pokemon to hit another in the invulnerability phase of Fly, Bounce, Dive, etc (as long as the move would normally affect the target).

Comment: Ok, for bonus points (well an extra kudo) how about abilities like levitate?

Comment: @IG_42: It doesn't ignore those either. You want Mold Breaker for that. What No Guard does is basically bypass the accuracy check.